# Computer starts for a second but then turns off

Tags: motherboard, power-supply

Yesterday I got a new motherboard as one of the RAM slots was not working. After I put the new motherboard in--keeping all my old components--the computer would start for a couple seconds and then turn off again and then after a couple seconds would turn back on and continued to do this until I turned the power off. I put the old motherboard back in and it then started for a second and then turned off without turning itself back on.

I have tested other PSUs but they have the same result.

Comment: What kind of processor is it does it have pins? also try it will only one stick of ram at a time.

Comment: It is an i7 3770, not sure whether it has pins or not (Not sure how that works), and I have tried with both RAM sticks, one in each slot and none, all have the same response. I have also tried without a hard drive and without the processor, still the same response.

Comment: Turns out it is a pinless processor

Comment: So you tried one in one slot booted it up then tried it in the other slot and repeated with the other stick of ram? Just trying to rule out a bad memory stick. It seems like its shorting or almost sounds like it did you were proper esd gear when switching out all the components? It only takes a little bit of esd to kill a component and it happens quite often im hoping thats not the case.

Comment: I know both memory sticks work, I had tested them both prior to switching to the new motherboard. Not even sure what esd gear is, do you think I may have broken something in the swapping process? What confuses me most is that it worked perfectly before with the old motherboard and now neither work.

Comment: You can Read about ESD [Here](http://www.computerhope.com/esd.htm) it sound like something may have shorted the motherboards out. One of your components possibly one of the PSUs caused this since you are having trouble out of both motherboards.

Comment: I guess I'll have to take it in to a shop somewhere and see if that's the case. Thank you so much for your help!